# Docker use image environment variable to mount volume

Tags: docker

Inside the docker file for jansendup/emdw-compile-dep I define the following variable:

```
ENV BIND_DIR /home/user/devel
```

Would it be possible to do something like this:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/ubuntu/devel:$BIND_DIR jansendup/emdw-compile-dep
```

instead of this:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/ubuntu/devel:/home/user/devel jansendup/emdw-compile-dep
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the variable would get expanded locally (and would probably be empty).

Docker also only accept absolute paths inside the container so doing:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/ubuntu/devel:. jansendup/emdw-compile-dep
```

or

```
sudo docker run -v /home/ubuntu/devel:~ jansendup/emdw-compile-dep
```

also won't work.

If you have some specific usecase for the above, feel free to add that. Then it might be possible to provide a better solution.